# Is there a system of automated sharing of current (experienced) weather between aircraft in flight?

Tags: weather, radio-communications, aircraft-systems, sensors

For example, if say - Aircraft 1 is flying a certain route, being followed by Aircraft 2 at an interval of say, 5 minutes (over the same position). Is there a system by which Aircraft 1 can transmit the weather it is experiencing at that moment to Aircraft 2? Something like crowd-sourcing weather from all on-board sensors of aircraft in the air? Akin to ADS-B for weather?

Comment: The closest thing that I know of right now is a PIREP, but its not automated and not "peer-to-peer". The only automated aircraft peer-to-peer communication I know of is for the TCAS system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The practical use of streaming data received from sensors installed on airplane](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/31053/the-practical-use-of-streaming-data-received-from-sensors-installed-on-airplane)

Comment: In addition to the PIREP system alluded to by @RonBeyer, PIREPs and other weather discussed on ATC frequencies is effectively available to all crews monitoring that frequency. ATC also tends to serve as a weather report aggregator and distributor, especially for such items as ride reports, icing, and cloud tops and bases. Other than these, there is currently no other system in place. It would be great if there were something such as what you describe. The PIREP system needs a major overhaul.

Answer (score 5):

Aircraft to aircraft, there is not.

Ground or satellite to aircraft exists in the form of [FIS-B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_dependent_surveillance_%E2%80%93_broadcast#Flight_information_services-broadcast_.28FIS-B.29), and other commercial providers.

---

However, aircraft to ground in an automated fashion **exists.**

It's called **Aircraft Meteorological Data Relay** (AMDAR).

> [It's] a program initiated by the World Meteorological Organization. AMDAR is used to collect meteorological data worldwide by using commercial aircraft.
>
> Data is collected by the aircraft navigation systems and the onboard standard temperature and static pressure probes. The data is then preprocessed before linking them down to the ground either via VHF communication ([ACARS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_Communications_Addressing_and_Reporting_System)) or via the [Aircraft to Satellite Data Relay].—[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_Meteorological_Data_Relay)

So, if it becomes widespread, FIS-B, et al., would benefit from AMDAR **if** they share the data. Thus realizing the aircraft to aircraft weather relay, in a sense.